# Serializing Model in Python/Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to serialize some models that represent user settings in a django template. Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var mutes = {{ user.appuser.mutes.all|safe }};
</script>
```

Instead of json, I get the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var mutes = [<Mute: Mute object>, <Mute: Mute object>];
</script>
```

I'm new to this and am clearly doing something wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `|safe` doesn't have anything to do with serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it's not a very good idea to directly serialize a django model for usage in the frontend, mainly because of security. What if there's data on your model that your users aren't allowed to read?

For this reason, you would usually create the objects in javascript manually:

```
var objects = [];

{% for model in models %}
    objects[] = {
        name: {{ model.name }},
        date: {{ model.date }},
        // etc.
    };
{% endfor %}
```

This way, only the data you explicitly define in your template get into the javascript. If your model changes in the future and gets sensitive data added, it won't appear in the javascript objects.

Comment: How would you pass the "models" variable into an external js file in this instance? Django will block doing so as it isn't JSON serializable

Comment: @mayankmehtani you can't just pass a Python object to JavaScript. You have to serialize the object to pass it to JavaScript. And then the same considerations as in my answer apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django's built-in [serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2), or use just the serialization functionality from [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#serializing-objects). I find Django Rest Framework to be a better option, even for simple tasks, because it's very flexible and requires less overhead in your own code.

Either way, you'll need to use `JSON.parse`, like so:

```
var mutes = JSON.parse('{{ serialized_value }}');
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `JSON.parse('{{ serialized_values|safe }}')`

Comment: In Django 3.2, there seems to have a safe way to pass a json to the template via the context with a template tag called JSON_SCRIPT: {{ json_file_context_name|json_script:"some_name" }}.
A <script> tag is generated in the page containing the serialized context and it can be handled further in a JS script using : var someName = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#some_name').textContent);